# Will making new chat rooms take a part of your reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, chat

I have just earned the privilege of making new chat rooms. Because of this i want to know that will making new chat rooms take a part of my reputation. I know that chats which follow from discussions don't take some part of your reputation as it follows from a question but what about the rooms which are made on your wish?

Here by taking a part of your reputation i mean like what happens when you cast a bounty a part of your reputation goes into that bounty. Does the same think happen in making chat rooms?

Comment: No. It does not.